# Flutter Getx different data on the same page

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

When displaying different data on the same page, I was wondering how you usually implement it?

For example, going from `user profile page A` -> `user profile page B` -> `user profile page C`,
Do I need to create a controller for each user, like `A ProfileController`, `B ProfileController`, `C ProfileController`?

Currently I'm trying to create 3 controllers, each with a userId in the Controller's tag, but I'm having some issues.

ex)

```
BINDING: Get.lazyPut(() => ProfileController(), tag: Get.argument);
ROUTING: Get.toNamed("/profile", arguments: A);
FIND: Get.find<ProfileController>(tag: A);
```

Then, I modified GetView to look for a controller that fits the Tag.

```
abstract class GetView extends StatelessWidget {
  const GetView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  ProfileController get controller => GetInstance().find(tag: Get.arguments);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context);
}
```

The problem here is the value that Get.arguments returns.

`user profile Page A` -> `user profile Page B` -> `user profile Page C` -> `other Page D`

If I change the values on page A in page D, the Get.arguments in the GetView on page A will return the arguments values on page D.

As a result, the GetView on page A will not find the correct ProfileController.

```
// Routing from Page C to Page D
Get.toNamed("/other", arguments: {"other": "something"})

// Change values from page A on page D
final controller = Get.find<ProfileController>(tag: A);
controller.changeValue();

// GetView on page A
final argument = Get.arguments; // {"other": "something"}
GetInstance().find(tag: Get.arguments); // FAIL
```

This makes it difficult to separate controllers by tag using arguments. because Get.argument is a global variable.

Please tell me the best case when changing to different data on the same page.

Thank you